# Looking for an interval training app that allows customize laps

Tags: running, app, interval-training

I'm looking for an android app that allows me to customize the intervals I want to train.

For example, training 3 minutes in maximum or near maximum intensity followed by 3 minutes of recovery time.Then another round of training 2:30 min by 2:30 mins of recovery and so on until 30 secs of training by 30 secs of recovery.

After that, the times will increase upwards to get again to 3 min of maximum intensity by 3 of recovery.

I have reviewed a lot of apps and none of them seem to have this feature?
Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Comment: [Impetus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.ohra.impetus) allows you to customize the intervals.

Comment: This is the app I was looking for! Thank you @TheGuy!